# NAudio - playback problem after changing assembly name

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscar

after changing the assembly name of my project in Visual Studio, audio playback using NAudio installed as nuget has become inaudible, with no other errors. This issue persisted even if I removed and installed the nuget package again.
For the playback, I am using AudioFileReader and WaveOut.

What can be causing these issues with NAudio after changing the assembly name?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "inaudible"? As in it _plays_ but sounds awful, or is actually silent?

Comment: By "assembly name" are you referring to the `.dll` file-name, the project-name, the namespace name, the Strong Name, the version, or something else?